# What does it mean when there's a "C'est" after "ce, cet, cettes, ou ces"?

Tags: grammaire, démonstratifs

In the sentence "Cette c'est de la merde, j'ai perdu cinq minutes de ma vie", why is there a "c'est" beside "cette" why can't you just say "c'est"? Why do people do this and is it necessary?

Comment: This "cette" just shouldn’t be there, it's not only ungrammatical it's plain nonsense,  no French speaking person would utter or write this. Either some words are missing, probably at least a noun after "cette", or  "cette" is misspelled. Can you be more specific about where heard or read the sentence?

Comment: Thanks! I've been wondering for such a long time, I first thought that but I started to doubt myself thanks!

Comment: Orally it might just be the effect of stumbling, searching for words: *C'est... c'est de la merde !*

Comment: It was in the sub titles though, and they were citing a comment posted on a video as a joke. I think it's just a mistake

Comment: Youtube comments shouldn't be trusted too much, they're often just automatic voice recognition and highly error-prone. As Law29 said, *C'est... c'est de la merde !* seems more likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this sentence is grammatically incorrect. I think that one word is missing. Based on the context, it could be "vidéo".

> Cette **vidéo**, c'est ...
>
> This video is ...

**Cette** is a "déterminant" which should come with a noun.

**C'est** is a contraction of "ce"(meaning "it") and "est" (meaning "is").